How do I configure a second WAN port to connect to a /29 network provided at a Data Centre?
The data centre are providing a host range (xx.xx.xx.204)-(xx.xx.xx.206) with a network: xx.xx.xx.200/29) for internet connectivity.
I can connect one of the three physical ports we have been provided to the WAN1 port on the Firewall (configured as a static ip) and we can then access the firewall on xx.xx.xx.204.  But how do I make use of the other ports? If I connect one of the other ports to WAN2 then the pfsense firewall config requires this second connection to be on a separate network (subnet). I’d like to use one of the ports for VPN access so I can have two external ip addresses (xx.xx.xx.204) and (xx.xx.xx.205).
Edited: I was hoping to make use of a second physical port for redundancy (e.g if I misconfigure the WAN port, which I just did, I would ideally like to be able to connect on a second interface to avoid having to go to the DC to fix my mistake). As far as I am aware the bandwidth is shared between the three ports the DC are providing

Why not connect one port and use virtual IP's on pfesnse? Do you require three ports for bandwidth or redundancy?

Redundancy. If one of the ports went down I’d like to still be able to access the firewall.

The only routing taking place on the firewall is to define the gateway provided by the data centre. All other routing is configured on a layer 3 switch.

For redundancy, you'll have to check with your provider, but I'd attempt to solve this at L2, using either an approach such as link aggregation or rapid spanning tree. Both essentially means bridging two ports in pfsense or creating a LAGG interface, dependent on what your provider supports.
For IP's, simply use IP alias.
